# How to check if user authentication or not in VueJs while using traditional laravel authentication

Tags: laravel, vuejs2

I am building an application using Vue, Vuex and Laravel.

The data for the JS is consumed using the steps in below link and it works fine. I use normal Auth::routes() for authentication.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript

But the tricky part for me is to update the Vuex state if the user is authenticated or not, as this is not a ajax request.

I need above especially for the case lie...Suppose in Vue component i have a  which should be visible only for authenticated user, I need a state which holds this information.

I can find lot of tutorials using JWT, where a action authenticates a user and updates the state, but not the traditional authentication method nad vue.

Could someone please help on this?

Comment: https://medium.com/carbono/laravel-api-vue-spa-authentication-354dbd9ef1b0 check this, it may help you

Comment: Thanks. I went through the link.They are basically checking for a cookie and setting the vuex state. But cookies by laravel is http only and cannot be read by javascript. Even though it can be changed, http only cookie is more secure. Is there any other option?